# How do I compare timestamp (variable=str) in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Hello I want to compare two timestamps (variable=string) to find out from the logfile of my server if the server is reachable. Therefore I want to compare the timestamp of my log with the current timestamp. Unfortunately I don't get my variable in the second method to compare the variables

```
def check_timestamp_now():
    current_datetime_now = datetime.now() # returns complete timestamp now like '2020-10-15 11:24:36.741997'
    current_datetime_string = current_datetime_now.strftime('%b %d %H:%M') # returns timestamp now like 'Oct 15 11:30'
    print('first')
    print(current_datetime_string)


def main():
    check_timestamp_now()
    
    try:
        print('second')
        value = '{} {}'.format(*get_date_str(s).groups()) # returns timestamp like 'Oct 15 11:30'
        print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my output:

```
first
Oct 15 13:42
second
Oct 15 13:42
```

Unfortunately I cannot compare these two strings to find out if my server is still available?

Comment: Of course you *can* compare two strings; but what is it you actually have in mind that the comparison should return? Also, what is `get_date_str`? What is `s`?

Comment: @MrFuppes ```get_date_str``` is my method to extract the timestamp (Oct 15 13:42) from the last line of my logfile and ```s``` is the query of the last line from the logfile. My goal is that I get a ```true``` if both timestamps are less than 2 minutes apart and a ```false``` if the difference in timestamps is over 2 minutes

Comment: ok, I'd suggest to compare datetime objects then, not strings. if you subtract two datetimes from one another, you get a timedelta, which you can compare easily against a threshold, like 2 minutes. The timestamp in your server's logfile, how is it formatted?